# html data-icon not rendering in IE (MVC3 application)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, icons

I have an asp .net MVC3 app that is working mostly as it should.

I am using data-icons instead of images in some places. These are rendering fine in all browsers apart from IE (v9). I am wondering why this is and what I can do to fix it?

For example I have a span which renders html that looks like the below...

```
<span class="navIcon" aria-hidden="true" data-icon=""/>
```

In most browsers it renders like this...

[image: working icon]

But in IE it renders like this...

[image: broken icon]

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason is that IE9 choose not to use any of the formats you have defined in the `@font-face` (for example IE9 is known from skipping the **.eot** and keep looking for **.woff** version). I suggest you use something like [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) in order to get all the different font variations. In the result your `@font-face` should be similiar to this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pictos';
    src: url('pictos-web.eot');
    src: local('☺'), 
    url('pictos-web.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('pictos-web.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('pictos-web.svg#webfontIyfZbseF') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you for this. I will try it shortly. I am actually seeing the same issue in Firefox as well. Would this be the same issue do you think?

Comment: @BenCameron Might be but I can't be certain. Despite what the issue is getting the `@font-face` right is the first step.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. The problem was with the urls in the fon-face section. They weren't quite right for all the formats. All sorted now.